# Subtotal Loop in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, sumifs

For simplicity, I have two columns in a spreadsheet; A & B.

Column A has levels: 5 to 8

Column B has costs

I need VBA code to subtotal costs as follows:

- If Level 7, then sum all Level 8's above it
- If Level 6, then sum all Level 7's above it
- If Level 5, then sum all level 6's above it

I've tried the attached but need to replace the text with a formula or find some other way.

[image: Excel screenshot]

```vb
Sub SumLoop()


    Sheets("Costing").Select
    LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = LR To 2 Step -1
    
        If Cells(i, 1).Value <> 8 Then Cells(i, 2).Value = "SUBTOTAL FROM ABOVE"
    
    Next i
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Is row 15 supposed to sum only rows 12-14, or rows 2-10 as well?

Answer (score 0):

Just wrote a quite similar function for my usecase.

You can iterate over the given Range and use Offset to check the Value you want.

In my Case I check if the clm -3 next to my my cell has the font colour RED, but you can check something else as well.

```
Function CashInRED(rng As Range)
    Dim objDictionary, intItems, p, strKey, CodeList
    Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim cell As Range
    
    'Itearates through all the cells in given Range
    For Each cell In rng
    
        'If it is a Red Project we consider this cell
        If (cell.Offset(0, -3).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)) Then
            'If Number is not yet used in the Dict we Add it
            If Not objDictionary.Exists(cell.value) Then
                objDictionary.Add cell.value, cell.value
                'Debug.Print cell
            End If
        End If
        
    Next cell
              
    'Redim the array
    intItems = objDictionary.Count - 1
    ReDim arrItems(intItems)
    p = 0
    
    'We add the elements to the array
    For Each strKey In objDictionary.Keys
        arrItems(p) = strKey
        p = p + 1
    Next
    'We sum up the entrys
    For Each cell2 In arrItems
        CashInRED = CashInRED + cell2
    Next

End Function
```